# Grouped or Multiple Foreign Key Constraints

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, constraints, ssms, foreign-key-relationship

I've got a situation where I want to restrict records in a table to only allow 2 columns to be populated together where they exist paired in another table record.

For instance:

1. **tblHome** (***Home_ID***)
2. **tblParent** (***Home_ID, Parent_ID***) --> ***Home_ID*** has to exist in tblHouse
3. **tblChild** (***Home_ID, Parent_ID, Child_ID***) --> ***Home_ID*** and ***Parent_ID*** have to exist on the same record in tblParent.

Is there a way to create a constraint to enforce relationship 3?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL declarative integrity constraint `FOREIGN KEY` says that a subrow value in a table has to appear as a subrow value somewhere else where it forms a superkey (`UNIQUE NOT NULL` or `PRIMARY KEY`). Otherwise you have to constrain via triggers. The case where a subrow value just has to appear as a subrow value somewhere else is called an inclusion dependency constraint and is not declaratively supported by SQL.

> 3. tblChild (Home_ID, Parent_ID, Child_ID) --> Home_ID and Parent_ID have to exist on the same record in tblParent.

As long as you have `(Home_ID, Parent_ID)` as `UNIQUE NOT NULL` or `PRIMARY KEY` in `tblParent`, you can have `FOREIGN KEY (Home_ID, Parent_ID) REFERENCES tblParent (Home_ID, Parent_ID)` in `tblChild`.